# Angular 5, IONIC 3 - [ts] Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post[]>'

Tags: ionic3, observable, angular5

[image]

This tutorial is asking me to map to JSON, I read that Angular 5 don't need to map to JSON. Could not get this work.

[GitHub](https://github.com/ArunEdathadan/DeepLinking) <- Project files

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Post } from '../../models/posts.inteface';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-posts',
  templateUrl: 'posts.html',
})
export class PostsPage {

  posts: Observable<Array<Post>>;

  constructor(private data: DataProvider,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.posts =  this.data.getPosts(); // Error 
  }
}
```

The tutorial is asking me to write this way.

[image]

This is the provider file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
/*
  Generated class for the DataProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  rootUrl : string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

  posts:string ='posts';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DataProvider Provider');
  }

  getPosts(){
    this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}`).map(res=>res).take(1);
  }
}
```

Updated like @Prasheel said, still error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular 5 then there is no need to use map operator. You just need to return the Observable like this :

```
 getPosts(){
   return this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}`);
  }
```

This will work. Or else you can explicitly define the return type like this :

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]>{
       return this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}`);
      }
```

Comment: please check, still, something is missing in my code

Comment: Did you specified the return type as well ?

Comment: I added like you have shown. Last screenshot, please see

Comment: Please try the another code snippet that I have provided. There might be a problem with type casting the models. Alternatively, you can replace Observable<Post[]> with Observable<any>

Answer (score 1):

**DataProvider** (you are missing the return statement. `map` and `take` operators are doing nothing).

```
getPosts() {
   return this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}`).map(res => res).take(1);
}
```

**Update**

```
.map(res=>res.json())
```

That is because the tutorial must be out to date, `res.json()` were the way to transform the `http response` before [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http) comes into play. Said that, you are not longer need to use `map` to transform the answer in `json` format. `Get` request returns an Observable that gets complete when the response arrived, so `take(1)` is not necessary either.

```
getPosts() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}`);
}
```

Comment: I have made that change, still the same. I have updated the question, can you take a look

Comment: It must be an error cause by your IDE, try to reload the project. In any case I updated the answer.

Comment: @Luilllyfe  Please check the last screenshot, still couldn't figure out.